# I'm using laravel 5.2 not using homestead, and i want to use homestead with configured 5.4 , will there be any issues?

Tags: laravel, homestead

I have my laravel setup on my local without using homestead, just wamp and configured host. And i want to install homestead with configured laravel 5.4 , will there be any issues on this set up?

because i want to preserve my apps on my local installation of laravel 5.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so i did install it anyway and the answer is you still have to upgrade to PHP 7, because the homestead installation uses the same PHP app what your local is using. so the solution i'm guessing is you have to have a separte php7 which i think would have issue or just upgrade to PHP 7 and upgrade all your laravel apps to the latest version.

Comment: or better use Laragon